# Need my PDF to be searchable when clicked

Tags: search, pdf, download

I have a link to a PDF on a site that the client wants to make searchable. It can be searched using Adobe reader's default search thingee. But, it has just come to my attention that when viewing it on Safari, it renders like a page in the browser, and it is only when I click download or preview that the search function becomes apparent.

I have since learn that how PDFs render are user-dependent.

I don't wish to force a download on anyone. I also tried storing a PDF in a cloud and providing a download link, but the same thing happens in my Safari browser as before.

Is there any way to force the search function to appear (probably a stupid question) - or am I better off providing instructions for how to search the PDF?

Here is the link in question (click the "View our wine list" link):

http://sheadavidsky.com/teatro/menus/wines.html

Thank you.

Comment: The link don't work for me...

Comment: Do you have a PDF document that is searchable in Safari? Or is this just a safari limitation?

Comment: Sorry, this is off topic.  Migrating to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer?pli=1).

Comment: No pretty - but that should do it. Thank you so much for your help.